# SQL Syntax error creating stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am creating a small (for now) stored procedure to insert some data. When I create this I get an error.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS InsertTESTData;
delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertTESTData (
p_pink_no VARCHAR,
p_carrier VARCHAR,
p_thisno INT
)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO RefDB (pink_no,carrier,thisno) 
    VALUES 
(p_pink_no,p_carrier,p_thisno);
END $$
delimiter ;
```

And the error I always get is a 1064 SQL error as follows.

> ```
> Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'p_carrier VARCHAR,p_thisno IN) BEGIN INSERT INTO RefDB (pink_no,carrier,t' at line 2
> ```

I thought I had everything covered and am now pulling my hair out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a length for your `varchar` parameters like this

```
p_pink_no VARCHAR(100)
```

and change

```
p_thisno IN
```

to

```
p_thisno INT
```

Complete example:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS InsertTESTData;
delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertTESTData (
    p_pink_no VARCHAR(100),
    p_carrier VARCHAR(100),
    p_thisno INT)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO RefDB (pink_no,carrier,thisno) 
    VALUES (p_pink_no,p_carrier,p_thisno);
END $$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Sorry the second one was a typo on my part when pasting into SO.  Adding the length has not made a difference and still get the same error

Comment: I just added the IN parameter to the beginning of all values and now it is working!  Strange as I thought this was default?

Answer (score -1):

you have to declare the size of the data type ,after thal i am sure your code will be execute successfully.
follow this

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS InsertTESTData;
delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertTESTData (
    p_pink_no VARCHAR(20),
    p_carrier VARCHAR(200),
    p_thisno number(23))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO RefDB (pink_no,carrier,thisno) 
    VALUES (p_pink_no,p_carrier,p_thisno);
END $$
delimiter ;
```